# Jquery - add event to link with hash specified

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to ask, if there is a way to add event to a link, witch particular hash ?
For example:

```
<a href="index.php/#about">About</a>
```

And then select this link in Jquery and add click event, for example:

```
$('a[href$="#about"]').click(function() {
            alert ('ok');
        })
```

This above will not work, i just want to show some pattern, what i want to archive.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`event.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/), to cancel default action.

> If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

```
$('a[href$="#about"]').click(function(e) {
  alert('ok');
  //Cancel default action
  event.preventDefault();
})
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/r33mv36t/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('a[href$="#about"]').click(function() {
      alert ('ok');
      return false;
})
```

Comment: `return false` is bad idea bcz it stops event propagation also. Better use `e.preventDefault()`